# How to access External url link in django

Tags: python, django

I want to access External web link
On my django website,but i dont access it so how to access it on button click action.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly, you want to create a button that redirect to an external website in your django template.

You can use an href and link the website you are trying to access.

```
<a href="https://example.com/">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you well, You could try embedding the button between anchor tags with the link you'd like to go to like so:

```
<a href="https://www.website.com"><button type="button">Button</button></a>
```